# getchar returns EOF before actual EOF

Tags: c

Question : Under which circumstances ( besides actually reached end of file ) is getchar function of C-stdlib returning EOF?

I aim to read an entire file into a memory buffer. So I thought I open a file, check it's size, allocate a buffer for it, if that worked out, then read each char of the file in a for loop into allocated memory:

```
int main ( int argc , char *argv[] )
{
    long cpos,epos,l;   
    int i;
    char *p;

    if ( argc == 1)
    {
        printf ("FAIL : no file specified\n");
        exit (-255);
    }
    else
    {
        myMdfFile = fopen ( argv[1] , "r" );
        if (myMdfFile == NULL)
        {
            printf ("FAIL : cannot open file %s\n" , argv[1]);
            exit (-254);            
        }
        else
        {
            fseek( myMdfFile , 0 , SEEK_END );
            epos = ftell(myMdfFile);
            fseek( myMdfFile , 0 , SEEK_SET );  

            pAll = malloc( epos );

            if ( pAll )
            {
                p = (char *)pAll;

                for (l=0;l<epos;l++)
                {
                    i = fgetc(myMdfFile);
                    if ( i == EOF )
                    {
                        if ( l == epos-1 )
                        {
                            printf ("NOTE : %u bytes read \n" , l);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf ("NOTE : file has error errno : %d [0x%02x]\n", errno , errno );
                            cpos = ftell(myMdfFile);
                            printf ("pos is at 0x%08x" , cpos);
                            printf (" ... ...  EOF is at 0x%08x \n" , epos );
                            printf ("Why is the file giving me at %d EOF actually %d bytes before real EOF\n" , l , epos - cpos );
                            exit (-248);                
                        }
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        *p = i;
                        p++;
                    }
                }
                free (pAll);    
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("FAIL : cannot allocate %u bytes of memory \n" , epos);
                exit (-255);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But getchar is not getting me what's in the file. It spontaneously decides to return an EOF:

```
D:\rampage\mdfun>mdfun.exe 3064213.mdf
NOTE : file has error errno : 0 [0x00]
pos is at 0x00002000 ... ... EOF is at 0x000b571b
Why is the file giving me at 7136 EOF actually 735003 bytes before real EOF
```

The 7137th byte ( l starts at 0 ) is 0x00 ( see also : [binary file 3064213.mdf contents at position of l at exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJZ3F.png) ).
At the position 0x2000 in the file are also plain 0x00. ( see also : [binary file 3064213.mdf contents at position of cpos at exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke5zd.png) ).

Btw why is there such a significant deviation between the number of getchar calls ( in l = 7136 ) and the streampointer position ( cpos = 0x2000 = 8192 )? Shouldn't getchar increment the streampointer position for each successfully retrieved character only by sizeof(char) ?

I am using mingw in a win7 dos shell:

```
Reading specs from C:/Programme/Razorcat/MSYS_MinGW/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --without-x --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Comment: Seeing the words "mingw" and "binary file", I suspect that some of your trouble comes from the `fopen` mode. Try `"rb"` instead of `"r"`

Comment: Given that this is Windows... have you tried opening the file in `"rb"` mode instead of `"r"`?

Comment: Awesome! That "rb" helped.

Comment: This question does not deserve a downvote..

Comment: What is `pAll`? Use self-explanatory names. The code is very hard to read,  worse to understand. See [ask].

Comment: What good would it be to check for `EOF` and the length? Just checking `EOF` is completely sufficient.

Comment: If you want the entire file, there are functions that do that for you. No need to read character by character.